# How to get SharedPreferences value from static class

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a preference saved on my xml file R.xml.my_prefs:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="host"
    android:text="www.whatever.com" />
```

I want to read it from my static class:

```
public class NetworkUtils{

    private string PREFERENCE = functionIWouldLikeToHaveToLoadPreferences(R.xml.my_prefs).get("host");  // <--- NO WAY!!!

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";

    private static URL buildURL(String path) throws MalformedURLException{
        return buildURL(path, new HashMap<String, String>());
    }

    private static URL buildURL(String path, HashMap<String, String> getArgs) throws MalformedURLException{
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("https");

        builder.authority(PREFERENCE);
        builder.appendPath("22");
        builder.appendPath(path);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : getArgs.entrySet()) {
            builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        Uri uri = builder.build();
        URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
        return url;
    }
```

but it looks I can't get the PREFERENCE from this class, I need an activity. Any way to do it without an activity context?

There are many static functions on that class that will use that PREFERENCE and others like it, so I would like to avoid having to pass the context to each one again and again, as it would make my life much more complicated. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your desire to avoid passing `Context` object to each and every static member. But that is the preferred way of handling system-related staff in Android.

If you have a child of `Application` class, you could initialize your `NetworkUtils` with its `Context` in `Application.onCreate` method. But remember to release a reference to global context in corresponding `Application.onTerminate` method.

Still I insist it's not a good idea to keep the `Context` object.

Have you thought of initializing `NetworkUtils` class with a previously read `PREFERENCE` object from some place which has access to `Context` value.

Comment: Yep, I guess I will have to do that in the end. Is just it feels wrong having to instantiate the thing on every Activity I need it, only to get a few variables. Looks like a little "overkill" to me.